# What gunner skills should a bow user avoid?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

Which gunner armor skills should I avoid as a bow user?  I was informed some of the skills only benefit bowgunners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The skills which benefit bowguns and *not* bows are:

- [Recoil](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/armor/skill/recoil)
- [Rapid Fire](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/armor/skill/rapid-fire)
- The various Shot+ skills (like [Crag S+](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/armor/skill/crag-s+)) which allow bowguns to load additional  types of ammo. Bows have an equivalent set of skills, Coating+ (such as [Power C+](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/armor/skill/power-c+))
- [Precision](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/armor/skill/precision)

It's also worth noting that for Bow Users [Reload Speed](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/armor/skill/reload-spd) +3 is equivalent to the +2 version (they both auto-load coatings)